# I can copy file but can not move it from my Mac Terminal

Tags: permissions, terminal, macintosh, move

I can copy file but can not move it on my Mac Terminal.

I want to execute following command:

```
mv /apps/gfss/ipt/files/R2R/Japan_WHT/21940000/DATA.xlsx /apps/gfss/ipt/files/R2R/Japan_WHT/21940000/inprogress/
```

And I get following error:

```
mv: rename /apps/gfss/ipt/files/R2R/Japan_WHT/21940000/DATA_21940000.xlsx to /apps/gfss/ipt/files/R2R/Japan_WHT/21940000/inprogress/DATA_21940000.xlsx: Permission denied
```

However, if I use `Finder`, I can move it. But I want to do this from Terminal.

But, I am able to `copy`:

```
cp /apps/gfss/ipt/files/R2R/Japan_WHT/21940000/DATA.xlsx /apps/gfss/ipt/files/R2R/Japan_WHT/21940000/inprogress/
```

Wondering what is that I am doing wrong!?

Below is the `ls -ltr` output:

```
gfss-apac-ipt2:21940000 admin$ pwd
/apps/gfss/ipt/files/R2R/Japan_WHT/21940000

gfss-apac-ipt2:21940000 admin$ ls -ltr
total 384
-rw-r--r--@ 1 alokur  wheel  193385 Nov 22 12:09 DATA_21940000.xlsx
drwxr-xr-x+ 2 admin   wheel      68 Nov 22 13:08 inprogress
```

P.S.: Move does not work even when I do `chmod 777 inprogress`; and I get same error.

Comment: Oh, negative voter, care to comment please? Negative voting without suggestions for improvement is bad and rather arrogant. Everyone is not perfect! I could not find solution on Google so asked here.

Comment: You need an `-a` and an `-e` on that `ls` command.

Comment: I didn’t downvote, but (1) It’s just common sense (and common courtesy) to do ```cd /apps/gfss/ipt/files/R2R/Japan_WHT/21940000 && mv DATA.xlsx inprogress/```, to eliminate the `/apps/gfss/ipt/files/R2R/Japan_WHT` directory path as being part of the problem, and to give us a shorter command to have to look at.  (2) If you know anything about Unix permissions, you know that permission to move a file between directories depends on write permission to the source and target directories, … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  so you should have used the `-a` option in your `ls` command to show us the mode of **`.`** (the source directory). (3) And even if you don’t know enough to do it on your own initiative, you should have done it when you were asked to. (4) If you know anything about `ls`, you know that `@` and `+` as the 11th character of a mode string indicates the presence of ACLs and/or other attributes, and you should have showed us those. (5) Permissions depend on identity. Your `ls` output shows that you are trying to move a file owned by `alokur` … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  into a directory owned by `admin` and protected 755 (full permission to the owner, `admin`, and read-only permission to everybody else) but you don’t say what user id you are running as. (6) This may be nitpicking, but, since you asked for suggestions for improvement: You say you are having a problem with a command that tries to move a file called `DATA.xlsx`, but your `ls` output doesn’t show that file — it shows some other file, named `DATA_21940000.xlsx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resolved**:

I had to delete the folder `/apps/gfss/ipt/files/R2R/Japan_WHT/21940000` and recreate it.
Then I `cd` to `/apps/gfss/ipt/files/R2R/Japan_WHT/` and gave permission to `21940000` directory using `chmod -R 777 21940000/`

I think there was some hidden directory inside `21940000` created by some other user and hence I was unable to do `chmod` before.